# How to tell `make-module-evaluator` to use a custom reader like #lang does?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to execute a custom made #lang on a given string (not in a file). Let's call it `broccoli`.

## Setup

My lang is defined as so:

### broccoli/main.rkt

```lisp
(module reader racket/base
  (require broccoli/private/reader)
  (provide read read-syntax)) ; basically a reprovide
```

### broccoli/private/reader.rkt

```lisp
(provide
  (rename-out
    [my-read read]
    [my-read-syntax read-syntax]))

(define (my-read in)
  (syntax->datum
    (my-read-syntax #f in)))

(define (my-read-syntax src in)
  (with-syntax ([parse-tree (parse src (make-tokenizer in src))]) ; brag stuff
    (strip-context
      #'(module program broccoli/private/expander
          parse-tree))))
```

### broccoli/private/expander.rkt

```lisp
(provide
  (rename-out [module-begin #%module-begin]))

(define-syntax-rule (module-begin expr)
  (#%module-begin
    (provide meal)
    (define meal (transform 'expr)))) ; some kind of computation
```

It works fairly well used the classic way :

```lisp
#lang broccoli
Hello world!
```

will produce:

```lisp
(module program broccoli/private/expander
  (program
    (sentence (word "Hello") (word "world"))))
```

which will then expand into:

```lisp
(provide meal)
(define meal (list 42 38)) ; the result is for the sake of the example, don't mind it
```

But I'm trying to apply it to an arbitrary string I get from a network request, and send back the result.
And this time, it gets more complicated.
Here's what I tried:

## Try #1

```lisp
(define text "Hello world!")
(define evaluator (make-evaluator 'broccoli text)) ; Error: no #%module-begin found
(evaluator 'meal)
```

## Try #2

```lisp
(define text "Hello world!")
(define module (broccoli-read-syntax #f (open-input-string text)))
(define evaluator (make-module-evaluator #:language 'broccoli/private/expander module))
(evaluator 'meal) ; Error: meal undefined
```

## Try #3

```lisp
(define text "Hello world!")
(define evaluator (make-module-evaluator (string-append "#lang broccoli " text)))
(evaluator 'meal) ; Error: meal undefined
```

## Try #4 (it works but it's not what I want)

```lisp
(define text "Hello world!")
(define module (broccoli-read-syntax #f (open-input-string text)))
(define ns (make-base-namespace))
(eval module ns)
(namespace-require ''program ns)
(define result (eval 'meal ns))
```

This last result works correctly, but it doesn't use a sandbox, and uses `eval` directly.
I'm sure there's a better way, but I don't get what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was sooo close!

I had to require the generated module inside the evaluator (which implies providing `#%app`, `#%top`, `#%top-interaction`, `require` and `quote` from the expander).

```lisp
(define evaluator (make-module-evaluator (string-append "#lang broccoli\n" text)))
(evaluator '(require 'program)) ; missing step
(evaluator 'meal)
```

What I find weird in this solution is that it doesn't behave the same way the documentation says:

```lisp
> (define base-module-eval
    (make-module-evaluator '(module m racket/base
                              (define (f) later)
                              (define later 5))))
> (base-module-eval 'later)
5
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `read-lang-module` to turn the string into a syntax object representing a module. And then use `make-module-evaluator`.